# Restore database that is part of an Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, high-availability

I have a few databases that were part of an Availability Group. The primary replica (production) databases were taken offline for maintenance then brought back online. the primary databases were then added to the AG with a state of synchronized. However, the secondary replica (DR) databases says restoring and I am not able to add them back to the replica. What is the easiest and safest way to get these databases in synchronizing state again?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about an Availaiblity Group (AG) - look in the log of the primary and secondary - do you see any errors about connections? What errors do you see?

Comment: Sounds like the log backup did not apply....that's what the Restoring status means...can you verify?

Comment: How did you take the database offline?  You should get an error message trying to take AG database offline. `Msg 1468, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The operation cannot be performed on database "AGTest" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.`

Comment: What was the err msg/reason join failed? check network/connection. Check log backups up to date, including backups that may have occured while you are prepping the instance and restoring backups. MS recommends suspending log backups until secondaries are in [synchronizing]( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/manually-prepare-a-secondary-database-for-an-availability-group-sql-server ).

Comment: thanks for the feedback i was able to resolve the issue by restoring the database with the transaction logs with NORECOVERY. Then once both primary and secondary replica had the same data then i was able to add the secondary database to the HAG

Comment: @Kefash You could add a detailed explanation of what you did to resolve the issue as your own answer. This would benefit the community.